# Delay Update operation until every entity is updated [HIBERNATE]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I currently have the following code:

```java
@Transactional
    public void updateSlots(@NotNull AbstractSlottedLabPatchDTO<?> slottedLabPatchDTO,
            @NotNull AbstractSlottedLab<?> slottedLab) {

        Long duration = slottedLab.getSlottedLabConfig().getDuration();
        List<? extends TimeSlot> timeSlots = slottedLab.getTimeSlots();
        LocalDateTime newStartTime = slottedLabPatchDTO.getSlot().getOpensAt();

        BiFunction<LocalDateTime, Integer, Slot> calculateSlotLambda = (startTime, offset) ->
                new Slot(startTime.plusMinutes(offset * duration), startTime.plusMinutes(offset * duration + duration));

        timeSlots
                .forEach(slot -> slot.setSlot(calculateSlotLambda.apply(newStartTime, slot.getOffsetSequenceNumber())));
    }
```

In the last statement, I am setting the slot property for each of the individual entities, which causes some problems as I have a unique key constraint, which can be seen below:

```java
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "lab_id", "opensAt" })
})
```

In the `forEach` operation, whilst updating the slot. The `opensAt` field can overlap as successive slots have not yet been updated. I've tried deleting all the slots and creating new ones, however, I'd rather **not** do this as other classes actively test for the presence of timeslots.

Thus, I am wondering if there is an operation which can delay the update and execute the update all at once?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To update data all at once. You should use a batch update. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

Comment: Detach entities from persistence context, then reattach and merge. Here you are an example: https://javabydeveloper.com/merge-re-attaching-detached-entities/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to defer the SQL constraint. You didn't specify which database you are using, but I think most DBs support deferring unique constraints.

If you can't do that, you'll have to flush changes in order to not run into the unique constraint violation.

> I'd rather not do this as other classes actively test for the presence of timeslots.

Even if you are using the READ_COMMITTED isolation level, this shouldn't be an issue. At the end of the day, the unique constraint will take care of ensuring consistency.